Relation between, pre, post, segment and total lengths in Tikz decoration
I am trying to place a single snake cycle perfectly in the middle of line as shown in the following figure (this figure is not perfectly in the middle tough):

However I cannot understand the relation between the pre length, post length, segment length and the total length of the line, and cannot place the snake cycle in the middle or at a any position I want.
The MWE is as follows:
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw [decorate, decoration={snake, amplitude=0.5cm,
pre length=1.0cm,
post length=1cm,
segment length=0.6153794cm}]
(0,0) -- (3,0);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Initially, I would assume that pre length + segment length + post length = total length. I understand that I dictate the total length, i.e. it is not derived.
But it does not work that way. In the above example
pre length = 1cm
post length = 1cm
total length = 3cm
However, when I set segment length = 1cm, which I would expect to achieve one cycle at the middle, I get the following:

Also, when I set segment length = 0.5cm, I get the following:

The limiting value of segment length that switches from one cycle to 1.5 cycle appears to be 0.6153794cm, but I could not figure out where this number is coming from. Using 0.6153794cm does not place the cycle perfectly in the middle as you can see from the first image.
Questions:

What  is the relation between the pre length, post length, segment length and the total length of the line?
How can I place a one cycle snake perfectly in the middle of a line, or at any location I want?


A decoration can and will use the segment length just as it pleases.
Here is the snake decoration from

texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/decorations/pgflibrarydecorations.pathmorphing.code.tex

% decoration snake
%
% This decoration produces a hopefully optically pleasing squiggly snake.
%
% Parameters: \pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude, \pgfdecorationsegmentlength

\pgfdeclaredecoration{snake}{initial}
{%
  \state{initial}[switch if less than=+.625\pgfdecorationsegmentlength to final,
                  width=+.3125\pgfdecorationsegmentlength,
                  next state=down]
  {
    \pgfpathcurveto
    {\pgfqpoint{.125\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{0pt}}
    {\pgfqpoint{.1875\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
    {\pgfqpoint{.3125\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
  }%
  \state{down}[switch if less than=+.8125\pgfdecorationsegmentlength to end down,
               width=+.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength,
               next state=up]
  {
    \pgfpathcosine{\pgfqpoint{.25\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{-1\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
    \pgfpathsine{\pgfqpoint{.25\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{-1\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
  }%
  \state{up}[switch if less than=+.8125\pgfdecorationsegmentlength to end up,
             width=+.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength,
             next state=down]
  {
    \pgfpathcosine{\pgfqpoint{.25\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
    \pgfpathsine{\pgfqpoint{.25\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
  }%
  \state{end down}[width=+.3125\pgfdecorationsegmentlength,
                   next state=final]
  {
    \pgfpathcurveto
    {\pgfqpoint{.125\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
    {\pgfqpoint{.1875\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{0pt}}
    {\pgfqpoint{.3125\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{0pt}}
  }%
  \state{end up}[width=+.3125\pgfdecorationsegmentlength,
                 next state=final]
  {
    \pgfpathcurveto
    {\pgfqpoint{.125\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{-\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
    {\pgfqpoint{.1875\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{0pt}}
    {\pgfqpoint{.3125\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{0pt}}
  }%
  \state{final}
  {
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
  }%
}%

What you want is state initial followed by down and end up this give the lengths:
+.3125\pgfdecorationsegmentlength
+.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength
+.3125\pgfdecorationsegmentlength

That is 1.125\pgfdecorationsegmentlength. If you want that to be equal to 1cm then you need \pgfdecorationsegmentlength to be 0.88888 cm like this:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [decorate, decoration={snake, amplitude=0.5cm,
pre length=1cm,
post length=1cm,
segment length=0.8888cm}]
(0,0) -- (3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


